# findstring in MAKEFLAGS don't working with ifeq

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use `find_j=$(findstring j,$(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))` to find if there is -j option, so when I `echo  $(find_j)` the value is `j`
but when I compare it `ifeq (j, $(find_j))` this returnes false
I cant understand where is the problem
my version of make is make-3.99.90

```
find_j=$(findstring -j,$(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS))) 
ifneq ( , $(find_j)) 
PARALLEL_ENABLED=true 
endif  
.PHONY: PRINT 
PRINT:  
   $(info $(PARALLEL_ENABLED))  
   $(info $(MAKEFLAGS))     
   $(info $(find_j))
```

```
---empty line---
--warn-undefined-variables -ws --jobserver-fds=5,6 -j 
-j
```

Comment: `make` variables are case-sensitive, so you will have to write `$(find_j)`, not `$(Find_j)`. Also, please show us your makefile too. Also, it would be better to search for a `-j` flag by doing `$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS))`, I think.

Comment: @Vroomfondel . yes sorry its my miss click, in makefile its right 
Updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that the release of GNU make you're using is a beta release of GNU make 4.0, which itself was released in 2013... so you're using a beta of a release that itself is 8.5 years old.

However, that's not related to this problem.

The issue is that the `MAKEFLAGS` variable's final value is not set until after all makefiles are parsed.  If you try to examine it before all makefiles are parsed, it will contain only a subset of the total set of options.

When you expand that variable as part of an `ifeq` or `ifneq` statement, that happens as the makefile is being parsed and so (as per the above) only the simple options (ones that don't take an argument: `-j` accepts an argument so is not "simple") are available.

When you expand the variable as part of a recipe, that happens after all makefiles are parsed: at that time the final value of `MAKEFLAGS` is set.  So your `$(info ...)` functions inside the recipe do the right thing.

This is easy to see:

```
$(info no recipe MAKEFLAGS is '$(MAKEFLAGS)')

all: ; $(info in recipe MAKEFLAGS is '$(MAKEFLAGS)')
```

If you run with `-j10` you'll get:

```
no recipe MAKEFLAGS is ''
in recipe MAKEFLAGS is '-j10 --jobserver-auth=3,4'
```

(your "in recipe" flags might look different because you're using such an old version of GNU make).

In the next release of GNU make, the value of MAKEFLAGS is kept up-to-date constantly so you can check it at any time and it will be accurate.  But that release is not available yet.

Comment: Thank You then I can use this `if [[ '$(MAKEFLAGS)' == *'jobserver'* ]] ; then echo with parallel ;else echo withoout parallel;  fi`

Comment: Simpler is to use make functions: `echo $(if $(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS)),with parallel,without parallel)`  As long as the test appears _in a recipe_, it will work, even when using GNU make functions.

Comment: Yes truly this is better, I can use it like part of command.
Thank You

Comment: My use case is to pass `--disable` to the `tqdm` command when run in parallel to suppress progress bars that I include with most targets, so adding the check per-target is unwieldy.

Comment: I've found that this works as a macro definition: `TQDM=tqdm $(if $(findstring j,$(MAKEFLAGS)),--disable,)`, both in the primary and sub-jobs.

Comment: I would not recommend that.  It will be true if there's any "j" character anywhere in `MAKEFLAGS`, not just for `-j` options.  The version I posted above using `filter` is more precise and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be imprecisely documented. While `MAKEFLAGS` has the flags like e.g. `-s` and `-k` as `ks` in it, the `-j` flag gets processed in another way: it is not stripped of the leading dash `-` AND it is not visible in the [first pass of processing the makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles). Only when rules are executed, `MAKEFLAGS` receives a value, albeit a processed form of the one you gave. `-j3` elicits a `-j3 --jobserver-auth=3,4` response from the command line transcriber of `make`, while `-j` stays `-j`. So what does this mean for us? Obviously the feature to detect the requested parallelism at runtime is not stable or there are some good reasons not to access them (which is the case most of the time when you encounter exceptional behaviour in GNU tools), so maybe you can give us more information on what you are trying to achieve - maybe there is a way to circumvent accessing the command line.

Comment: The problem is that this makefile is called by another makefiles cascaded and I need to find out if parallel build is enabled and, based on this, call the appropriate command for cmake build, which in turn can work either with msbuild or unix makefile build . I don't want to lose the ability to control parallelizm.
Thank You